# \$\Vert\boldsymbol{E}_{}\Vert=\Vert\boldsymbol{v}_{}\Vert\cdot\Vert\boldsymbol{B}_{}\Vert\cdot\sin^{}\left(\theta\right)~\$is seemingly not applied

Tags: electromagnetism, homework, math

I want your help to find whether the misprint exists or not .

$$  H  :=\text{magnitude of the uniform magnetic field which comes from leftside}   $$

$$  a:=\text{radius of the cylinder-formed dielectric}  $$

$$  \sigma :=\text{electrical conductivity of the dielectric}  $$

$$  \omega_{} :=\text{angular speed of the cylinder}  $$

The central axis of the cylinder is placed vertically against the uniform magnetic fields .

$$  v:=\text{speed at a point where the distance is } ~ r ~  $$

$$  \therefore ~~ v= r \cdot \omega_{}  $$

$$  B:= \mu_{0} H ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{magnetic flux density at vacuum?}  $$

[image]

I know the below  general formula .

$$  \boldsymbol{ E }_{} = \boldsymbol{v}_{} \times \boldsymbol{B}_{}   $$

$$  \therefore ~~ \Vert  \boldsymbol{ E }_{}   \Vert  = \Vert  \boldsymbol{ v }_{}   \Vert \cdot \Vert  \boldsymbol{ B }_{}   \Vert \cdot \sin^{}\left(\text{angle between the 2 vectors} \right)  $$

The textbook wrote the below .

$$  E= v \cdot B \cdot \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) =\underbrace{\omega_{} r}_{v} \underbrace{\mu_{0}H}_{B} \left( \underbrace{ -\cos^{}\left(\theta_{} \right)}_{\sin^{}\left(\theta_{} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)}  \right)   $$

However , of course \$~ \cos^{}\left(\theta_{}\right) = \sin^{}\left(\theta_{} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)  ~\$ should be held , a negative sign must not be appended .

Can I completely assert that this is a misprint? Or some physical conception(s) is(/are) hiding here?

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the text book formula. I suspect that at \$\hat{a}_z\$ or \$\hat{k}\$ denoting the vertical axis is present in the text book formula.

Comment: Seemingly no such symbols are in the statements in the book.
[Not written in English][https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Pz5.jpg]

Comment: I can see the symbol `E` separated from the symbol `z` by a short symbol, to the immediate left of the image just before the equation block starts. If you can read the language, what does that phrase say ? Does it say something like "*E along z direction is ...*". If so, that sentence can be taken as a stand-in for vector notation.

Comment: Yes, the phrase says " ```E``` is oriented in the z-axis" , or "```E```  points the direction of z-axis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, at \$\theta = 0\$, \$\vec{v} \times \vec{H}\$ is pointing in the negative z direction. This may be where the negative sign is coming from. At \$\theta = 0\$,
$$
\vec{v} = c_1 \hat{j}\\
\vec{h} = c_2 \hat{i}\\
\vec{v}\times\vec{h} = c_1 \cdot c_2 \cdot \hat{j}\times\hat{i} = c_1 \cdot c_2 \cdot(-1) \cdot \hat{k}
$$

where \$\hat{i}, \hat{j}, \hat{k}\$ are the unit vectors pointing in the positive \$x,y,z\$ directions.